# Trouble creating MDX set/calculated member

Tags: visual-studio, mdx, cube

I'm new to MDX and struggling to create either:

1) A static set that references a dynamic date
2) A new calculated member that a static set can reference instead

I have been able to retrieve the values I want in a query scope command, like below:

```
    WITH MEMBER [Time].[Date].[Yesterday] 
    AS VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now()-1,"MM-dd-yyyy")
    SELECT [Time].[Date].[Yesterday]  ON COLUMNS 
    FROM
    [Test Cube];
```

But this  does not translate to the functions in Visual Studio. I would love to be able to make a set like below:

```
CREATE SET CurrentCube.[Test]
AS {[Time].[Date].&[20160613] : [Time].[Date].&[20160620]},
DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Test' ;
```

...except have yesterday's date as the member at the beginning of the range. 
If not possible, alternatively I would like to know how to create a new calculated measure in the time dimension. Syntax is all wrong, but concept is captured with:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Time].[Date].[YesterDay]
AS VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now()-1,"MM-dd-yyyy"),
FORMAT_STRING = "MM-dd-yyy";
```

Any help here would be very much apprecaited!!!

EDIT: Should mention that LastChild() and Tail()/NonEmptyCrossJoin() do not work with my data set as the time dimension is populated with dates until the end of the month. All measures (i.e. GRS) are empty, however, so if there was a way to have it select LastChild() date that has been updated with data that would do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Does any of this syntax help? It is assuming the key for you Date dimension if formatted like this 'yyyyMMdd'

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now()
     ,'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
      '[Time].[Date].[Date].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today]
    + ']' 
  SET [Today] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    )
```

I think the above translates into CREATE scripts relatively easily:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.[Key for Today] AS 
'Format(Now(),'yyyyMMdd')';

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.[Today string] AS 
''[Time].[Date].[Date].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']'';

CREATE SET CURRENTCUBE.[Today] AS 'StrToMember([Measures].[Today string],constrained)'
```

One you have something in place like the above then the following is a lot easier...

```
SET [TodayLstYr] AS 
    ParallelPeriod
    (
      [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year]
     ,1
     ,[Today]
    ) 
  SET [ThisYear] AS 
    {
        Ancestor
        (
          [Today]
         ,[Date].[Month Calendar].[Calendar Day]
        ).Item(0)
      : 
        [Today]
    } 
  ...
  ...
```

---

**Straight in cube**

The following approach is much more performant than creating members and measures in the cube script.

To include `Today` in your cube add a column "Today" into your Date table. Base the column on an expression such as this with a name `DW Today`

```
case when convert(carchar(8), FullDateAlternateKey, 112) =
          convert(carchar(8), GetDate(), 112) 
  then 'Yes'
  else 'no' 
end
```

Then in VS drag the new column of the Date dimensions table into the attributes. Leave the relation to the key attribute as is - flexible.

---

To find the last date member with data:

```
TAIL(
  NONEMPTY(
    [Time].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
  )
)
```

Comment: The syntax makes sense! Should have mentioned in the original ask though-- the problem is not getting a single query to have the date range I want, it's inserting a permanent set into the cube's calculations so a user can always filter by yesterday's date. As far as I could ascertain, a with clause does not work with CREATE SET CurrentCube or CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube commands in Visual Studio.

Comment: @HouseHay better to add a `IsPastDate` flag as a new attribute in your date dimension. If you want to use `Create` then it should be easy enough to translate the above?